# Test click event on a "web-component" button with Storybook

Tags: typescript, web-component, storybook

I'm looking on the Internet for an example about how to test **click event** on a button (**web component/typescript**) with Storybook, but I can't find a clear one.
Can you suggest me some guides/articles or code snippets?

I already created the **stories.ts** file; it's something like this:

```
import { html, TemplateResult } from 'lit';
import './index.ts';
import { Properties } from './model/button.interfaces';

export default {
  title: 'My button',
  component: 'my-button',
};

interface Story<T> {
  (args: T): TemplateResult;
  args?: Partial<T>;
  argTypes?: Record<string, unknown>;
  parameters?: any;
}

interface ArgTypes extends Properties{}

const Template: Story<ArgTypes> = (args: ArgTypes) => html`
      <my-button 
          ?disabled="${args.disabled}"
          color=${args.color}>
        ${args.text}
      </my-button>`

export const Button = Template.bind({});

Button.args = {
  label: "This is the text",
  color: "primary"
}

Button.argTypes = {
  color: {
    control: 'select',
    options: ['primary', 'secondary'],
    table: {
      category: 'Modifiers',
    },
  }, 
  disabled: {
    control: 'boolean',
    options: [true, false],
    table: {
      category: 'Modifiers',
    },
  }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: `Can you suggest me some guides/articles or code snippets?` - simply, no, we can't. We help you fix issues & debug your code, we can't do that with code that doesn't exist

Comment: I added my code :(

Comment: `Can you suggest me some guides/articles or code snippets?` - you're asking for code

Comment: If you have issues with your code as it exists, edit your question to say as such, including an [mre] and telling us your errors

Answer (score 0):

Since web components work as native html elements, you can attach an onclick attribute to your `<my-button>`.
Try adding a script tag above your component in which you define an onclick handler and add it to your component.

```js
const Template: Story<ArgTypes> = (args: ArgTypes) => html`
      <script>
          const clickHandler = () => console.log('clicked')
      </script>
      <my-button 
          ?disabled="${args.disabled}"
          color=${args.color}
          onclick="clickHandler()">
        ${args.text}
      </my-button>`
```

Now you should see the log whenever you click on the button.